# Symfony check validation for non exist field

Tags: forms, symfony

This is my form

```
class CandidateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('dob')
            ->add('user', new CandidateUserType());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Candidate',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'candidate';
    }
}
```

In my first screen system get only first_name last name and user details. I need use this form in second screen. But I no need to show first name and last name fields in that view. I really need show only birth day.

So i show my form like this.

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'candidate_form', 'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}

        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>DOB</label>
                {{ form_widget(form.dob, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.dob) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
                    COMPLETE
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

I have used `render_rest` for not show unwanted field. But system check validation for firstName, lastName and user field also.

I have used validation group. But it override current value and save these fields as blank.

This question might be duplicate. What is the correct way to do this? Should i implement another form for show dob of candidate?

Comment: use validation groups in your form

Comment: I used validation groups. But it override my old values.

Comment: You want to manage your form in two different step (multistep)? If you don't persist your data in some way (Session,etc) your data is lost between the two interaction. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) bundle for a multistep form flow. Yest, validate it with the validation group

Comment: I have to use another form type for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either you add parameters to pass to your formtype and :

```
private $show_fl;

public function __construct($show_fl = true){
    $this->show_fl = $show_fl;
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if($show_fl) {
             $builder
                ->add('firstName')
                ->add('lastName');
        }
        $builder->add('dob')
            ->add('user', new CandidateUserType());
    }
```

or use another formtype.

You can also use the $options of the buildForm without using a construct.